# Extracting a Zip file. How can I do this using a partial file name for the Zip?

Tags: vba, excel

So here's the scenario. Everyday, there is a Zip file created called "Bundle_06112018063917" (The numbers are the date and time at which the zip is created, therefore they change everyday).
The code below extracts all the files into a separate folder beautifully!

```
Sub UnzipAFile(zippedFileFullName As Variant, unzipToPath As Variant)
    Dim ShellApp As Object
        'Copy the files & folders from the zip into a folder
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    ShellApp.Namespace(unzipToPath).CopyHere 
    ShellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).items
End Sub

Sub Dump()
    Call UnzipAFile("G:\DP\Mstanley\history\JUN18\WESTROCK\Bundle_06112018063917.zip", _
    "G:\DP\Mstanley\history\JUN18\WESTROCK\Dump")
End Sub
```

**The Problem:**
The name of the zip file changes everyday based on the date and time in which the zip is created. Therefore I need a way to refer to zip file with just "Bundle_".

Below is what I tried, but still no luck.

```
Sub doingstuff()
    Dim pSTR As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim dirFile As String

    pSTR = "G:\DP\Mstanley\history\JUN18\WESTROCK\"
    strFile = "Bundle_" & "*" & ".zip"
    dirFile = Dir(pSTR & strFile)

    Call UnzipAFile(dirFile, "G:\DP\Mstanley\history\JUN18\WESTROCK\Dump") 
End Sub
```

Any ideas/help would be much appreciated!

Comment: In this folder are more zip files then with Bundle_ prefix?

Comment: If the date part of the filename was created as yyyyMMdd then they would sort alphabetically instead of you needing to parse out the MMddyyyy part to order them, in case there is more than one Bundle_ zip file.

Comment: @GadziuYes there are multiple zip folders titled bundle just with different dates/times

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all the files and do whatever you want to the files that you want to handle.

When you're done, move the file to an archive folder.

```
    Dim di As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("C:\ExampleDir\")

    For Each fi In di.GetFiles()
        ' Unzip file file
        ' do stuff to the contents
        ' move the file to an archive folder
    Next
```

Comment: Although the question includes the tag [VB.Net], it is obvious that the OP is using VBA.

Comment: That would change it to FindFirst/FindNext, but still requires iterating through the files.

Comment: There are multiple zip folders, so I wouldn't want to extract them all. Is there a way you could loop through them like this and test for a zip file beginning in bundle_ and most recently created?

Comment: Sure. you can test for whatever you want and unzip or not. In fact, you can create a "high water mark" file and only unzip files that are newer, then update the timestamp on the high water mark file for the next run.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the signature of your `UnzipAFile` sub. Do you really want to accept any variable type or do you want strings?

This will search a folder for the latest "Bundles_" file and unzip that one. I couldn't make sense of the "date" at the end of the bundles files so I'm using the Date Modified on the zip file itself.

This solution required a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime (the `scrrun.dll` file)

```
Sub UnzipLatest(bundlesFolder As String, unzipToPath As String)

    Dim fil As File, fol As Folder
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim latestDate As Date, latestFile As String, latestBundleFileFound As Boolean
    If Not fso.FolderExists(bundlesFolder) Then Exit Sub

    Set fol = fso.GetFolder(bundlesFolder)
    For Each fil In fol.Files
        If fil.Name Like "*Bundles_*" Then
            latestBundleFileFound = True
            If fil.DateLastModified > latestDate Then
                latestDate = fil.DateLastModified
                latestFile = fil.path
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If latestBundleFileFound Then
        UnzipAFile latestFile, unzipToPath
    End If
End Sub

Sub UnzipAFile(zippedFileFullName As String, unzipToPath As String)

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. where is the scrrun.dll supposed to go?

Comment: @JesseReising When you add the reference I'm just pointing out which file you're looking for. Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Comment: Ah gotcha, so this looks like it would work. This may be dumb question but can how I get this to run? I might not be calling it correctly

Comment: Did you call `doingstuff` from an event (A button click, a form opens, Excel opens)? If so then do it in there. Otherwise you need to pass in the parameters some how. You can either do it in the immediate window (ctrl+G while in the VBA IDE) or create a button which call a parameterless sub then in that call this function. Before calling through you'll need to establish your parameters. Maybe they are hardcoded or maybe they live in a special cell somewhere in your file?

Comment: Ok cool, I'll see what I can do. Another question though, in my original script  (The one I said works) when I call UnzipAFile(Name, Path) if I try and put a variable in place of the name, I get a run time error at the ShellApp.Namespace line stating Object variable or with lock variable not set. I don't get this error if I use the written path. Why is that? Is there a way I can use a variable in that call?

Comment: @JesseReising Does the error happen on line `ShellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).items` ? What if you do `ShellApp.Namespace("" & zippedFileFullName).items` instead? I think some of those shell functions need to be passed a string literal instead of a variable. I don't know why but concatenating an empty string seems to help.

Comment: Yep sure does.Still errors with the quotes. Here is the line I would like to work. 
`Dim BundleName As Range
    BundleName = Workbooks("WestrockVBA").Worksheets("sheet2").Range("a2").Value`


`Call UnzipAFile(BundleName, "G:\DP\Mstanley\history\JUN18\WESTROCK\Dump")`